# Harvest two pictures from open Facebook profiles

Tags: c#, php, facebook

I want to grab 2 pictures from say - 200 FB profiles.

The users can be random, but the photos should be profile pictures - not just from a random album.

Has anyone written anything like this or got any tips for rolling my own in PHP or C# ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I should clarify: the important factor is to grab 2 images from the same user - and OF the same user (not just photos from their albums).

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch the users picture with this URL:

http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture

Replace username with the user you like to get the photo of.

Also see for other options:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Answer (score 2):

If you have profile ID's, you can access them through this url:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/0000000/picture?type=large" alt="" />
```

Where obviously the 0000000 is the users profile name or vanintry url name.

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly use: PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can do fabulous stuff with it.